# Are there published stats for regular soldiers in Pathfinder 2e?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, npc

The Pathfinder 2e Gamemastery Guide includes stats for a bunch of NPCs, including bandits, pirates, and (city) guards, but it doesn’t include any kind of soldiers. Looking at the online indexes for the Bestiaries, I also didn’t see anything.

I’m looking for stats for (by default human) archers, men-at-arms, infantry soldiers, legionnaires, cavalry, knights, sergeants, captains, etc. People trained to fight together in formation as part of a military unit.

Have stats for these kinds of NPCs been published anywhere for Pathfinder 2e?

Ideally I’d like official material from Paizo (since it seems like it ought to exist somewhere), but if there’s good third-party resources for this that’s OK too.

Comment: Are you looking only for Paizo official material?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Ideally yes but not a hard requirement; I added that to my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## There are a Few "Soldiers"

I maintain a [list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BP7v4Alf7977fKyLVDXkhKNx33fh1e1csR0zAapzKiM/edit?usp=sharing) of every creature and hazard printed in Pathfinder 2e, and there have been a few creature entries released with "Soldier" as the description.

Outside of the Convergent Soldier as a bit of a special case given the narrative of the book, the rest of the humanoid options would probably qualify as regular soldiers at substantially different levels of capability.

### Humanoid

- Hobgoblin Soldier - 1st level, *Bestiary 1*
- Convergent Soldier - 16th level, *Extinction Curse: The Apocalypse Prophet*
- Russian Soldier - 4th/6th level, *Pathfinder Society Scenario #2-8: A Frosty Mug*
- Human Soldier - 5th level, *Pathfinder Society Scenario #3-16: Escape from Oppara*
- Nagaji Soldier - 2nd level, *Bestiary 3*
- Ulfen Soldier - 3rd level, *Pathfinder Society Scenario #4-3: Linnorm's Legacy*
- Veteran Ulfen Soldier - 5th level, *Pathfinder Society Scenario #4-3: Linnorm's Legacy*
- Human Soldier - 15th level, *Blood Lords: Ghost King's Rage*
- Human Soldier - 9th level, *Kingmaker*
- Tengu Soldier - 8th level, *Stolen Fate: The Choosing*

### Non-Humanoid

- Skeleton Soldier - -1st level, *Pathfinder Society Scenario #1-18: Lodge of the Living God*
- Clockwork Soldier - 6th level, *Bestiary 3*
- Terra-Cotta Soldier - 6th level, *Bestiary 3*
- Planar Terra-Cotta Soldier - 11th level, *Fists of the Ruby Phoenix: Despair on Danger Island*
- Skeletal Soldier - 1st level, *Book of the Dead*
- Einherji Soldier - 16th level, *Stolen Fates: Worst of All Possible Worlds*
- SootSoldiers/Radiant Sootsoldiers - 10th level, *Rage of Elements*
- Ghost Soldier - 4th level, *Sky King's Tomb: Cult of the Cave Worm*

### Troops

> A troop is an organized collection of component creatures, typically Small or Medium in size, working as a cohesive whole. A troop is 16 squares in size and has two Hit Point thresholds in their HP entry, under which it reduces in size to 12 squares and then 8 squares. A troop has the Troop Defenses, Form Up, and Troop Movement abilities. Most troops have a weakness to area damage.

There have also been several creatures printed with the [Troop](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=367) trait, which would function well for circumstances where you're looking for more than one soldier. The only troop explicitly labeled as "soldiers" would be the sootsoldiers above, but many of the options would follow the theme like the [Hellknight cavalry brigade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1091).